# Who is "user 109"?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, users

I found out that **user 109** launches pulseaudio on startup, which blocks mine:

```
petr@sova:~$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio
109       1515     1  1 15:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
petr      2344     1  0 15:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
petr      2807  2757  0 15:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
```

Because of that, I can't access the sound card and get dummy outputs only. Once I kill the 109's process, everything works fine.

Who is user 109 and how do I prevent him from launching pulseaudio? My suspicion is that it's somehow connected to LightDM.

EDIT:

```
petr@sova:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep 109
speech-dispatcher:x:109:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file /etc/passwd to find out the username.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep 109
speech-dispatcher:x:109:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh
```

This tells us that user id 109 corresponds with the username 'speech-dispatcher'. This user's home directory is '/var/run/speech-dispatcher'.

There's also a package [speed-dispatcher](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/speech-dispatcher). It provides a high-level interface to Text-to-Speech systems according to its [homepage](http://live.freebsoft.org/desktop#speech-dispatcher), so it seems logical a program using this interface needs access to pulseaudio.

Find out what program is using speed-dispatcher and why it's spawning its own pulseaudio  session.

Going from the links above I'd start looking at the configuration of desktop accessibility related applications.

Comment: Sorry to downvote you, but this post doesn't really answer the question. Can you explain who `speech-dispatcher` is and what its role is?

Comment: [speech-dispatcher](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/speech-dispatcher) 'provides a device independent layer for speech synthesis.'. In order to do this, it seems logical that it would need access to PulseAudio.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single master list of all the default system users in Linux. You can list them by looking at `/etc/passwd` and in general from there you need to look at the package associated with the user name, in this case speech-dispacher

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/speech-dispatcher

> Common interface to speech synthesizers

Home page http://devel.freebsoft.org/speechd

> Speech Dispatcher project provides a high-level device independent layer for access to speech synthesis through a simple, stable and well documented interface.

The package is maintained by "Ubuntu Accessibility Developers "